# json文字列をdata属性で扱うときのエスケープについて

Tags: javascript, json

javascriptの配列をJSON.stringify()して、それをjQueryで動的に生成したhtmlコードのdata属性に組み込むときにエスケープする必要があります。

```
    function escapeHtml(text) {
    return text
          .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
          .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
          .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
          .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
          .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
    }

var json_array = ["a", "b"];
$('div').html('<p data-json="'+escapeHtml(JSON.stringify(json_array))+'"></p>');
```

これではjson文字列の「"」までエスケープしてしまい、data属性を取得して配列に戻すときのJSON.parse()でエラーになってしまいますので改善策を教えて頂けますか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

どのようにdata属性を取得しようとしていますか？挿入方法の善悪はさておき、提示されたコードで問題なく動いていると思いますが……

```js
function escapeHtml(text) {
    return text
          .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
          .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
          .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
          .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
          .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
    }

const json_array = ["a", "b"];
const $wrap = $('.wrap');
$wrap.html('<p data-json="'+escapeHtml(JSON.stringify(json_array))+'"></p>');
const $data = $wrap.find('[data-json]');

console.log($data.data()); // {json: ["a", "b"]}

console.log($data.attr("data-json")); // '["a", "b"]'
console.log(JSON.parse($data.attr("data-json"))); // ["a", "b"]

console.log(($data[0].dataset.json)); // '["a", "b"]'
console.log(JSON.parse(($data[0].dataset.json))); // ["a", "b"]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrap'></div>
```

Comment: 申し訳ありません。このコードの部分に原因があると、一部を抜き出してこの質問をさせて頂いたのですが、この回答を見て、違う場所に原因があった事に気づきました。ちなみに「善悪」とありますが、一般的にはどの方法が善なのか教えて頂けますか？

Comment: まあ自分には良し悪しが正しく評価できないってのもあります……(個人的には`$p=$('<p>');$p.attr('data-test', JSON.stringify(['a','b','c']));`のようにDOM操作するほうがエスケープも不要で好きですが)

Comment: あ、 @think49 さんの回答にあるように第二引数でもいけましたね

Comment: DOM操作のエスケープだと「"」がエスケープできないという記事を見たのでこの方法をとっていました。

Answer (score 0):

既にクローズされていますが、エスケープせずとも書けます。

- [jQuery() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

```js
'use strict';
var p = jQuery('<p>', {'data-json': JSON.stringify(['a', 'b'])});
jQuery('div').append(p);

var array = JSON.parse(jQuery('div>p[data-json]').attr('data-json'));
console.log(array); // ["a", "b"]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます、参考になります